# If a list1 containing some elements of list2. Does list1 also changes if list2 changes?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, sudoku

This is what I am trying to create.

```
list2 =[1,2,3];

list1= [list2[0],list2[1]];

list2[0]=2;

print(list1);
```

I want the output to be [2,2] not [1,2]

Comment: I think you meant print(list1)

Answer (score 0):

Integers in Python are *immutable*. This is the behaviour you are expecting with the list, but it is not possible. Consider this example:

```
x = 0
y = 0
print(id(x), id(y))
y = 1
print(id(y))
```

Output:

```
94583099374048 94583099374048
94583099374080
```

Whereas lists are [*mutable*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
a_list = ["a",
                 "b",
                 "c",
                 "d",
                 "e",
                 "f"
                 ]
b_list = a_list
print("a list id before update", id(a_list))
print("b list id before update", id(b_list))

a_list += ["g"]
print("a list after update", a_list)
print("b list after update", b_list)
print("a list id after update", id(a_list))
print("b list id after update", id(b_list,))
```

Output:

```
a list id before update 139734649089472
b list id before update 139734649089472
a list after update ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
b list after update ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
a list id after update 139734649089472
b list id after update 139734649089472
```

This explains the behaviour you are seeing. `list1` and `list2` are stored in separate memory locations because you haven't equated the lists themselves. And therefore there is no link between `list1[0]` and `list2[0]`.

Note: `id()` returns the memory address of an object.